# Value for Z-axis affect the Y-axis

Tags: modeling

When I create a simple cube the objects blue Z-axis is ponting up, but when I'm still in object mode and want the change the dimension in the N menu, it's not working like when I create a new file.

I want to change the hight and enter a new value for the Z, but it affect the Y axis! I compared with a new file and there it was all OK, but not in my current scene. It worked well from start. I think I have activated some settings without knowing and I'm a bit lost and not nowing how to reset this setting or what it could be?

Comment: It sounds like you have rotated the cube at some point and you either have scaling set to local, or you just need to _Ctrl-A_ the object and apply the rotation.

Comment: @bertmoog Thanks for your comment! Every new cube I create act the same way, but it works when I use CTRl + D and select rotation. But I can't do that for every new object. There must be some other settings?

Comment: Can you post a few pictures?  You're saying that the arrows are oriented the correct way, but when you scale it, it doesn't scale in the direction of the arrow?  Did you mean Ctrl-A?

Comment: @bertmoog I'm not scaling, I just change the Z value below the Dimension options in the Transform menu. A new cube has a Z value of 2 meters and I change it to 1 meter, but it affects the Y axis instead!

Comment: Yes I mean CTRL-A.

Comment: Are you going to "Add->Mesh->Cube"?  If so, on the left hand side of the screen, it has a tool-bar with the title "Add Cube".  What is the rotation set to?  It should be x=0, y=0,z=0.  Press "T" if it's not there

Comment: @bertmoog It's 0,0,0

Comment: Is that the method you're using to create the cube?  In other words, you're not using Shift+D to duplicate the same cube, right?  If so, the new cube will carry the same rotation.

Comment: I crete a new cube with SHIFT + A then Mesh and Cube. But it seem to be working now! I don't know how many cubes I have created and none of them worked, but when I changed the Align to World instead of Align to view in the User Preferences, it works! This is strange! How could that affect the axis if I create a cube in front ortho or User Perspective?

Comment: Good deal... in View mode, it's always X & Y,  no matter the view, because you're looking through a 2-D screen

Comment: Yes, but if I create the cube in user perspective it's 3D and Z value affects Y value, is that really correct?

Comment: You're very welcome, I just added some pictures to maybe clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Align to: View** mode, the cube is created as the user has the view oriented:
[image]

[image]

Whereas in **World** mode, the cube is created aligned with the world axes (irrespective of the user's view):

[image]

[image]

Also, make sure your transform orientation is set to Global is you want to transform your object based on world axes:

[image]

Comment: Aligning added primitive to view is also possible via Last Operator panel once object is added, see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/types.html#common-options