# Meshes added depend on the viewport and are not placed on their default place

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view

It's quite hard for me to describe the issue in words.

I'm gonna drop these pics to explain the issue.

Say I have my 3d-view this way:

[image]

When I add a mesh, it's created and placed in the 3d-view this way:

[image]

I want it placed upon creation this way, however my 3d-view is directed to:

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81842/value-for-z-axis-affect-the-y-axis/81849#81849

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value for Z-axis affect the Y-axis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81842/value-for-z-axis-affect-the-y-axis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the tools panel (Press the T key) to have access to the creation parameters (or press F6 after adding your mesh). Make sure that the Align to view box is disabled.

[image]

If the question is about why is the mesh not created at the center of the grid, then the answer is that objects are created where the [3D cursor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/3d_cursor.html?highlight=cursor) is on the scene.

[image]

To reset the 3D cursor to the center of the grid press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>